# Ignoring formula based columns when using "currentregion" for data population

Tags: excel, vba, encoding, rowcount

I'm trying to make an expense report form for work for my coworkers to use and I've run into a problem.

The form finds the next empty row in the spreadsheet and then writes the data into that row. The problem is that the first three columns of my sheet are formula based and drag down throughout the entire spreadsheet. Because I am using the "currentregion" property, this means that the form writes the new details after all the formulas, even though they are blank and depend on the input. Here is my code for the data entry (there is more, but this is the relevant part).

```
Rowcount = Worksheets("Data Entry").Range("D1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Entry").Range("D1")
    .Offset(Rowcount, 0).Value = Me.txtDOY.Value
    .Offset(Rowcount, 1).Value = Me.cboClient.Value
    .Offset(Rowcount, 2).Value = Me.cboProject.Value
    .Offset(Rowcount, 3).Value = Me.cboType.Value
    .Offset(Rowcount, 4).Value = Me.txtDescription.Value
    .Offset(Rowcount, 5).Value = Me.txtAmount.Value
    .Offset(Rowcount, 6).Value = Me.txtMiles.Value
    .Offset(Rowcount, 7).Value = Me.txtRate.Value
End With
```

I've been able to counteract this by entering a blank column between column C and D (cutting off the current region from the formula based columns) but this is a roundabout way of doing it and looks untidy. Is there a clean way to do this that lets me leave the entire table as one contiguous block? I assume it's through the rowcount property but I can't figure out how to program it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding the last populated row in column D. Assuming the code is in the code module of the worksheet in question (that's what "me" is in the code below)...

```
With Worksheets("Data Entry")
    Rowcount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Comment: Gene you are a lifesaver!!! I've been trying to figure this out for hours and couldn't find a clear guide to explain how rowcounts work. Thank you very much :)